# How do I simply change the text of a label of a field in wordpress using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

AppSumo requires that the "Discount code" field be renamed "AppSumo Code". Without accessing the FTP, can I do this in the "customize CSS" section of my Wordpress site?

I also have to change the "Apply" text to "Redeem AppSumo Code".

Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riNEN.png)https://www.molo9.com/my-account/membership-checkout/?level=4

I have tried

```
label.pp-discount-code {
visibility: hidden !important;
}

label.discount-code {
visibility: hidden !important;
}

.pp-discount-code {
visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

to hide the discount code label so that I could use

```
.pp-discount-code:before {
content: ‘Enter your AppSumo Redemption Code below’;
visibility:visible;
}
```

but none of this is working. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to particular label

In the CSS: make font size 0 to this label to hide existing text and create a before sudoku element from CSS, in the before add the content whatever you wanted to display in place of a hidden label

Example:
Name

CSS:

```
label.hidetext {
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

label.hidetext:before {
    content: "Full Name here";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```